# ¿Son igualmente validos estas soluciones?

Tags: python, python-3.7

quería saber por que estas dos soluciones son igualmente validas para resolver el problema

Problema = Dados dos numeros (a,b) si alguno de los dos es igual a 10 o si la suma de ambos es igual a 10 return True si no return False

Esta es la forma como lo hice

```
def makes10(a, b):
  if a == 10 or b == 10 or (a + b) == 10:
    return True
  else: 
    return False
```

y  esta es la otra opcion para resolverlo, mucho mas simple

```
def makes10(a, b):
  return (a == 10 or b == 10 or a+b == 10)
```

Comment: Son válidas porque hacen exactamente la misma validación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ambas formas dan el mismo resultado.

La segunda forma es más compacta y "pythonesca". Los paréntesis, sin embargo, son innecesarios.

En la segunda forma evalúas una expresión lógica, que produce un resultado `True` o `False`, el cual retornas de inmediato.

Es la forma preferida en Python.

C no tiene variables lógicas; simplemente interpreta el cero como falso y cualquier otro valor como verdadero.

Comment: Que tiene que ver C en esto?

Answer (score 0):

Hola lo que sucede es que python asigna variables dependiendo de su contenido en este caso python detecta que lo que debe retornar es un valor boolean o en otras palabra true o false
entonces si pones return true python detecta que ya retorno un valor boolean que es lo mismo que return (a == 10 or b == 10 or a+b == 10) que si lo que dice esta condición  es que si se cumple alguna entonces es verdadero que es igual de valido ya que retorna un true o un false.

Answer (score -1):

no uso python, pero básicamente ambos resultados te van a dar una respuesta true o false, la diferencia esta en la condición, osea estas afirmando que en un caso te de true o en el otro de ser así false... en la segunda ecuación la "pc" te va arrojar si el resultado es verdadero te va arrojar un true, un 1, o algún valor verdadero en caso falso o un null, vació, un 0 o false

Comment: Porqué respondes una de pregunta de Pyhton si no usas Python?

Comment: el lenguaje da igual, lo que importa es la logica...

Comment: Si no entendio el autor que me pida explicacion el, gracias!

Answer (score -1):

Como dice @Candid Moe, es una comprensión Pythonesca (comprehension). En este caso, como bien dices, ambas expresiones devuelven el mismo valor.

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]

Comment: Gracias, tomo nota